# Unique index in Spring Data Neo4j 4

Tags: spring, indexing, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

How can I ensure uniqueness:

- for property of an graph entity?
- for combination of several properties simultaneously?

Currently I use SDN 4.0.0.RC2. I peek [the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.0.0.RC2/reference/html/#_index_management_in_spring_data_neo4j_4) and it seems SDN 4 not supports this feature now (but will support in future). Did I understand correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> for property of an graph entity?

Use cypher to create a (possibly unique) index on a property:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(name)
```

Unique index (aka constraint):

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:Person) ASSERT p.name IS UNIQUE
```

From http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-schema-index.html#schema-index-create-index-on-a-label

You can execute this automatically when you bootstrap your spring context:

```
@Component
public class IndexCreator {

    @Autowired
    Neo4jTemplate neo4jTemplate;

    @PostConstruct
    public void createIndexes() {
        try {
            neo4jTemplate.execute("CREATE INDEX ON :Person(name)", null);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // index already exists?
        }
    }
}
```

> for combination of several properties simultaneously?

This is not directly supported. You can concatenate multiple properties into one and create an index on that (while keeping the original properties to be able to access them). Or (as pointed out by Michael) you can use array property to store multiple values.

Comment: Thanks! Can you clarify how to execute cypher statements during spring context bootstrap?

Comment: You can use array properties as a compound index workaround

Comment: @MichaelHunger can you show an example of what do you mean, saying about 'array properties'? And how it is better, than concatenation of multiple properties into one?